# Access private http server

Tags: node.js, remote-access, portforwarding, socks, http-tunneling

I built a Nodejs HTTP server. It's running on localhost:3000.

**From outside the Local Area Network, how does one make a request to the private HTTP server? Messing with the router manually is not an option; process should be automated.**

I've looked at various techniques - and I'm confused:

1. Mapping the localhost port to the external ip address ([node-nat-pmp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-nat-pmp))
2. HTTP tunneling ([node-tunnel](https://github.com/koichik/node-tunnel))
3. SOCKS ([shadowsocks-nodejs](https://github.com/clowwindy/shadowsocks-nodejs))
4. CONNECT method in request header

It seems that everything is built for a client tunneling out through a firewall, I want to tunnel a request in through the firewall and to a private server. Or just run the localhost port on the external ip.

Any help would be appreciated. ***Confused.***

Comment: This has nothing to do with node really. It's the same as running a private server on any web technology. Do what you'd do if you were using Apache. Probably get your ISP to assign you a constant IP address, get the domain to point to it (set the DNS), and connect the computer directly to the internet. That would be the 'easiest'.

Comment: I've never run a private server that needed access from the WAN. A constant/dynamic IP address is not my issue, I can ping the external ip without a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access an internal service from outside of your network, you typically have two options:

1. Configure Port Forwarding on your router - You mentioned this isn't a possibility
2. Use UPnP to ask your router to open a port for you - This is often disabled as it is a security risk, but if not, look into https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-nat-pmp

Comment: Unfortunately, the router that I'm using doesn't support NAT-PMP, only NAT-UPNP. However, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.